# Hidden row expansion in DataTable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I have a question about hidden rows in DataTable. I'm aware that there is an example provided here at http://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html, but my situation is a little bit different.

I have an `ElementGroupViewModel` that contains an `ElementViewModel PrimaryElement` and `ElementViewModel[] LinkedElement`. In the DataTable, each row contains an `Element`. In my View, I have something like this

```
           foreach ( var item in Model )
            {
                @Html.Partial( "_ResultItem", item.PrimaryElement )
                foreach ( var linkedItem in item.LinkedElement )
                {
                    @Html.Partial( "_ResultItem", linkedItem )
                }
            }
```

I want it to show `PrimaryElement` first, and a user can expand/collapse each row to show/hide `LinkedElement`. Also, I want each page to show 30 `PrimaryElement` records regardless of how many `LinkedElements` are shown.

I'm not sure how I can achieve this. Anyone has any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use this structure because you are generating a nested static table that would not be compatible with DataTable source.

Could you generate primary master table using the primary elements without linked elements, and make Ajax calls that loads HTML for linked element from another controller,  and load it in the fnOpen. You can find example on the http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Expandabe-DataTable-MVC.aspx

If you do not want to make Ajax calls you can generate each linked sub-array as a separate hidden tables something like:

```
<table id="linked-1">
      linked set 1
</table>

<table id="linked-2">
      linked set 2
</table>

<table id="linked-3">
      linked set 3
</table>
```

and replace Ajax call from the example on the code project with some JQuery that finds linked table by the id of the row and pass the linked table inner HTML to fnOpen.

I hope that you see what is idea here.

Jovan